Degree axiom for P1 or P2
I am getting stuck on equation (7.33) on p. 192 of Cox-Katz's Mirror Symmetry and Algebraic Geometry. This concerns the degree of a cohomology class used as input for a Gromov-Witten invariant.
Let $X$ be a projective algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$. The Degree Axiom states that for $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n \in H^*(X, \mathbb{Q})^{\otimes n}$, the cohomology class $I_{g,n,\beta}(\alpha_1,\dots, \alpha_n) \in H^*(\overline{M}_{g,n},\mathbb{Q})$ has degree $$2(g-1)\dim X + 2\int_\beta \omega_X + \sum_{i=1}^n \deg \alpha_i.$$ Here $I_{g,n,\beta}(\alpha_1,\dots, \alpha_n)$ is a Gromov-Witten class defined by $\pi_{2!}(\pi_1^*(\alpha_1\otimes \cdots \otimes \alpha_n)$ from $\pi_1: \overline{M}_{g,n}(X,\beta) \rightarrow X^n$ given by $\pi_1(f,C,p_1,\dots,p_n) = (f(p_1),\dots, f(p_n))$ and $\pi_2: \overline{M}_{g,n}(X,\beta) \rightarrow \overline{M}_{g,n}$ given by (possibly) contracting unstable components.
The Degree Axiom states that $I_{g,n,\beta}(\alpha_1,\dots, \alpha_n)$ is a top-degree class iff $$ (7.33) \hspace{2cm} \sum_{i=1}^n \deg\alpha_i = 2(1-g)\dim X - 2\int_\beta \omega_X + 2(3g-3+n).$$
The convention here is that $-\int_\beta \omega_X = \int_\beta c_1 TX$, and I am doing something wrong here. If $X = \mathbb{P}^1$, for instance, and $g=0, \beta = d\cdot \ell$, then does this read as $\sum \deg_{i=1}^n \alpha_i = 2 +2d - 6 + 2n = 2d+2n-4$? I think I am doing something wrong with $-\int_{d\ell} \omega_{\mathbb{P}^1} = d$.
If $X = \mathbb{P}^2, \beta = d\ell, g=0$, then is it true that $\int_{d\ell} \omega_{\mathbb{P}^2} = d$ from these conventions? For $X=\mathbb{P}^2, \beta=d\ell, g=0$, I would read the right-hand side of (7.33) as $2\cdot 2 + 2d - 6  + 2n = 2d + 2n -2$.
The reason I am coming across this is because I want to enumerate all (possibly) non-zero genus 0 Gromov-Witten invariants for $\mathbb{P}^1$, to start. If $d=0$, then up to permuting the inputs, the only possibly non-zero invariant is $\left< I_{0,3,0} \right>([pt],[\mathbb{P}^1],[\mathbb{P}^1]) = \int_{\mathbb{P}^1} [pt] \cup [\mathbb{P}^1] \cup [\mathbb{P}^1] = 1$. If $d>0$, then by the Fundamental Class Axiom, all inputs must be $[pt]$, rather than $[\mathbb{P}^1]$. This leaves $\left< I_{0,n,d} \right>([pt], [pt], \dots, [pt]) = \int_{d\cdot \ell} [pt] \left< I_{0,n-1,d} \right>([pt],[pt],\dots, [pt])$ for $d>0$ by the Divisor Axiom for $n>0$. Again from the Degree Axiom, I am getting that $2n = 2d+2n-4$, so that $d=2$. I should be getting $d=1$ as the only possibly nonzero GW invts with $d>0$.

By the Euler exact sequence (or other considerations) the first Chern class of $\mathbb{P}^r$ equals $r+1$ times the hyperplane class.  You are missing the factor $r+1$ in your formulas.

Of course! Thank you!
